open the perf and test, but it's found that there are the unknown section , so how to get rid of the unknown section
I don't know how to get rid of the unknown section
and I use the following command to collect the perf.data
perf record -F 99 -a -g -- sleep 60
and then
perf script -i perf.data &> perf.unfold
but when I parse the perf.unfold and there are the unknown progress in the kernel state and usr state
perf could parse the unknown section correctly

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
